# Validar dni en la base de datos

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Muy buenas gente..necesito un poquito de ayuda...tengo un formulario hecho por el cual el usuario debe ingresar un nombre, dni, sexo..por el cual luego se guarda a una base de datos...tengo que hacer una funcion en javascript que compruebe si el dni ya fue ingresado..si este dni ya fue guardado cuando apreto en el boton "guardar" me aparezca un cartel de error y no me deje guardar...saludos y gracias por su tiempo..estoy trabahando con mongodb y nodejs

Comment: Bienvenido.Lucas., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc, saludos!

Comment: Puedes hacer un ajax para validar este campo cuando le den click en el boton guardar, este ajax envia lo que captura el usuario y lo compara con la BD

Comment: ahh si eso es lo que estoy tratando de hacer...pero me podrías pasar de como seria el código mas o menos,,?

Comment: Pega el código que lleves, selecciónalo y da clic en el icono {} otro consejo no pidas que te hagan el código así no funciona esta comunidad

Answer (score 2):

Mira algo como esto con Jquery

```
    function Get_Campo(DNI){
        var salida="";
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>",
            data:({
                funcion:"Validar_DNI",
                dni:DNI
            }),
            dataType:"html",
            async:false,
            success:function(msg){
                salida=msg;
                return salida;
            }
        }); 
        return salida;
    }

    var G=Get_Campo($("#DNI").val());
if(G=="1") alert("Existe");
```

Esta llamada `<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>` hace referencia al archivo actual en PHP, se puede reemplazar por el archivo donde este la conexion a la BD de tu validador

Comment: muchas gracias y en esta parte del codigo  url:"<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>"  me tira error, que debo poner en su lugar...?

Comment: Es la ruta de la pagina donde esta el script que valida esto <?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?> significa en PHP el nombre que tiene el archivo actual puedes poner "index.php", "validador.php", etc...

Comment: Lo ideal es que el OP MUESTRE  su avance ya que de cierto modo contribuyes a preguntas de baja calidad pues le estás dando directo la respuesta

Comment: Alfredo no lo había tomado en cuenta, la intención era aportar pero tu observación es bien recibida. Gracias por tu comentario :)

Comment: no se como subir el codigo..soy nuevo en esta comunidad..

Comment: Agregalo como una respuesta, selecciona tu texto y dentro del editor de texto que te muestra busca el botoncito de código :)